# OS X 10.7 doesn't detect my WPA2 Enterprise server-side password changes

Tags: mac-osx, osx-lion, wpa2

I have a Meraki wifi network that's authenticating via RADIUS to an Active Directory.  Users log in with their AD username and password via WPA2.  That all works.  However, when a user changes their AD password (due to expiration, forgotten password, whatever), their Mac doesn't prompt for a new password; instead, it just can't connect to the wifi.  To fix this we have to go into Network Preferences -> Advanced -> Wifi -> Preferred Networks, delete the network, then make a new connection.  This is kind of clunky, and gets us a helpdesk call every time.

Any ideas on what we could do about this?

Comment: Please stop editing your title with insignificant changes to bump your post. If you really want a lot of eyes on it, offer a bounty.

Comment: I'm trying to clarify what I'm looking for.  I felt that the old title was misleading, and thus causing people to not look?  Sure, I'll put a bounty on.

Comment: I've filed an Apple bug report, #11419560.

Comment: My bug has been closed as a duplicate of 10996590, which I can't see.  Thanks, Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A talk with Apple tech support says that, indeed, there's no automatic way to do this.  10.8 doesn't seem to have changed this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

A possiblly easier thing to do is delete the keychain entry for the wifi, or just change the password in keychain.   Sorry I don't have a better option off hand.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Not much easier than poking at the Network Preferences manually, but many easier to automate?  Dunno.  I probably don't want an automatic job that deletes keychain entries :)

Comment: I would write a script or small app that would allow the user to do this on their own. You can remove these entries by deleting a plist (I forget which one though).

Comment: Login.keychain is the file, but that hold everything. I don't know of a way to just remove a single keychain entry through a script.